# Какие на данный момент есть методы скачивания файлов?

Tags: c++, boost

Допустим, есть определённый набор файлов, от маленьких до больших (несколько ГБ). И есть много клиентов, у которых установлена наша программа на C++ и которым нужно эти самые файлы загрузить. На данный момент реализовал в виде обычной HTTP загрузки с нашего сайта. Скорость загрузки, естественно, оставляет желать лучшего, особенно если забить канал.

Итак, какие ещё есть современные варианты реализации данной задачи, для достижения хорошей скорости загрузки независимо от кол-ва качающих (в разумных пределах)?

Желательны кроссплатформенные способы с использованием Boost или других библиотек, но не откажусь и от Windows API. В крайнем случае интересны решения на QT, но на данный момент он в проекте не используется.

Comment: Организовать что-то в стиле торрент - кто скачал, начинает раздавать... :)

Comment: Используйте торренты